# Ruby: Generating An Array

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I'm trying to automate a test. Is there a better approach to solving this? I'm trying to create an array that only contains multiples of three and nothing else.

```
(1...100).each_with_object([]) { |i, a| a << i if i % 3 == 0 }.reject { |i| i % 5 == 0 }
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what series of numbers you're after, but every number which is evenly divisible by 3 is evenly divisible by another number. If `x` divides evenly by 3 to give `y`, `x` will divide evenly by `y` to give 3. There are no numbers except for 3 and 9 which meet your criteria of being "multiples of 3 and nothing else" and that's assuming you'll disregard that every number is a multiple of 1.

Comment: I had an interview that involved doing FizzBuzz with RSpec. I came up with a good solution, but I didn't have time to automate my tests. I want to ensure that this array I would create would only print "Fizz" for multiples of three and three alone. I would do the same thing for multiples of five. Instead of saying: ```[3, 6, 9].each { |x| expect(fizzbuzz(x)).to eq('Fizz') }```

Comment: @meagar: "(multiples of three) and nothing else". not "multiples of (three and nothing else)". :)

Comment: @Amadan I thought the rejecting multiples of 5 was the beginning of attempting to filter out all the numbers that were multiples of something besides 3, which would have left a pretty empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an array that only contains multiples of three and nothing else.

Using the `Numeric#step` enumerator:

```
3.step(100, 3).to_a
```

creates all multiples of three up to 100.

Your code seems to have an additional effect of filtering out the fives too. You can filter them out:

```
3.step(100, 3).reject { |i| i % 5 == 0 }
```

Or you can do something completely different:

```
require 'set'
((1..100).to_set - 3.step(100, 3) - 5.step(100, 5)).to_a
```

A bit more legible than the reject way, but probably a bit slower.

Comment: I've never used step, very cool. You taught me something new. :-)

Comment: `(1..100).to_set` can also be written `Set.new(1..100)`.  I wasn't aware that `to_set` could be used to convert an Enumerable object (and, hence, Enumerator objects such as `3.step(100,3)`, since Enumerator include`s Enumerable) to a set, but [that it does](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), but I still don't understand why there is no `Enumerable#to_set`.  I only find `Set.to_set`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `map` the digits 1 to 33 by multiplying each by three, then rejecting the multiples of 5?

```
(1..33).map { |i| i * 3 }.reject { |i| i % 5 == 0 }
```

Comment: I totally forgot about map! Thanks for that insight.

Comment: +1 for map and lowering the number of enumerations.You could even do  even `(1.33).map{|i| i * 3 unless i * 3 % 5 ==0}.compact!`

Answer (score 0):

A million and 1 ways to iterate in ruby

```
(1..100).collect{|i| i if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0}.compact!
(1..100).select{|i| i if i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0}
```

Here's another one and it reads really nicely

```
(1..100).find_all{|i| i % 3 ==0 && i % 5 !=0}
```

Comment: `collect` doesn't really fit here; use `select` or `reject`

Comment: fair enough since I have to call `compact!` added `select` as well